# mongodb group and count elements of an array propert

Tags: mongodb

I have these two collections

customers:

```
[
          {
            "_id": 1,
            "NAME": "CUSTOMER A"
          },
          {
            "_id": 1,
            "NAME": "CUSTOMER B"
          }
        ]
```

tickets:

```
[
          {
            "_id": 1,
            "CUSTOMER": 2,
            "NUMBERS": [1,2,3]
          },{
            "_id": 2,
            "CUSTOMER": 2,
            "NUMBERS": [4]
          },{
            "_id": 3,
            "CUSTOMER": 1,
            "NUMBERS": [25]
          }
        ]
```

I need to count how many numbers each customer has on the tickets ordered from highest to lowest in this way

result:

```
[
          {
            "_id": 2,
            "NAME": "CUSTOMER B",
            "COUNTNUMBERS": 4
          },
          {
            "_id": 1,
            "NAME": "CUSTOMER A",
            "COUNTNUMBERS": 1
          }
        ]
```

the example that came closest to what I need was this one but it's still not what I need

```
db.tickets.aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$CUSTOMER"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$CUSTOMER",
            NUMBERS: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $lookup: {
            let: { "customerId": "$_id"},
            from: "customers",
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$customerId"] } } }
            ],
            as: "CUSTOMER"
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
  // Join the customers collection to get the customer names
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      localField: "CUSTOMER",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "customer_info"
    }
  },
  // Flatten the array from the lookup
  { $unwind: "$customer_info" },
  // Group by customer ID and count the numbers in the NUMBERS array
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$CUSTOMER",
      NAME: { $first: "$customer_info.NAME" },
      COUNTNUMBERS: { $sum: { $size: "$NUMBERS" } }
    }
  },
  // Sort by COUNTNUMBERS in descending order
  { $sort: { COUNTNUMBERS: -1 } }
])
```

Comment: Accept it as a solution :)